# Making a grid with dots on vertices using React three fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am trying to make a grid with dots using React three fiber. I tried using LineDashedMaterial, but it is not perfect. I am new to threejs. Any idea how to make a surface with dots using a grid or a plane?

```
<Canvas frameloop="demand" camera={{ position: [75, 1, 0.1], zoom: 15 }}>
<mesh>
    <gridHelper
        material={
          new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({
            dashSize: 0.1,
            gapSize: 1,
            vertexColors: true,
          })
        }
        rotation-y={[Math.PI / 2]}
        position={[0, 12.5, 0]}
        onUpdate={(grid) => grid.computeLineDistances()}
      />
</mesh>
</Canvas>
```

Codesandbox: [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/grid-test-zy2lw9?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwy0006356hlp4ui8gu%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwy0002356hcw41fzb3%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwy0003356h4phb6eiy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwy0005356hsbrbp59x%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqp08wwy0002356hcw41fzb3%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwx0001356h7dy04dtj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwy0002356hcw41fzb3%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwx0001356h7dy04dtj%2522%257D%252C%2522clqp08wwy0005356hsbrbp59x%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwy0004356hef3gf3kd%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwy0005356hsbrbp59x%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwy0004356hef3gf3kd%2522%257D%252C%2522clqp08wwy0003356h4phb6eiy%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqp08wwy0003356h4phb6eiy%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A42.64612954186414%257D)

What I am trying to achieve is something like this

[image]

Comment: sandbox not working

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz here is the correct link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/grid-test-zy2lw9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import * as THREE from "three";

export default function App() {
  const pointsGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const sideLength = 10;
  const numPointsPerSide = 20;
  const pointsPositions = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numPointsPerSide; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numPointsPerSide; j++) {
      const x = (i / (numPointsPerSide - 1)) * sideLength - sideLength / 2;
      const y = 0;
      const z = (j / (numPointsPerSide - 1)) * sideLength - sideLength / 2;
      pointsPositions.push(x, y, z);
    }
  }

  pointsGeometry.setAttribute(
    "position",
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(pointsPositions), 3)
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Canvas frameloop="demand" camera={{ position: [75, 1, 0.1], zoom: 4 }}>
        <mesh position={[0, 0, 0]}>
          <cylinderGeometry args={[1, 1, 25, 32, 64, false]} />
          <meshBasicMaterial color={0x00ff00} />
          <meshBasicMaterial color={0xff0000} />
          <points
            geometry={pointsGeometry}
            position={[0, 12.5, 0]}
            rotation-y={-Math.PI / 2}
          >
            <pointsMaterial color={0xff0000} size={0.1} />
          </points>
        </mesh>
        <OrbitControls />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/grid-test-forked-8dmwy4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A6%2C32

Comment: Thank you,  I was also working on a similar solution.